# Bootstrap Modal ASP.NET

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap, modal

Estou criando um app mobile usando o bootstrap modal, asp.net (aspx).
Um link href dispara o modal e precisa enviar ao modal valor contido em atributo do tipo data-* que foi criado. O objetivo é preencher uma label contida na modal no momento de sua abertura e isto não está acontecendo. A label preenche somente após a modal ser aberta da 2a tentativa em diante. Na 1a tentativa de abertura a label não preenche. Quando a modal é fechada clicando o "sim" (1a tentativa) e em seguida reabrindo o modal, funciona; clicando o "não" o problema persiste. Agradeço se puderam ajudar.

O link href:

```
    <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" data-marcacao="frase">
```

O script:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $('#myModal').modal({ backdrop: 'static', keyboard: false });
        $('#myModal').modal('toggle');

        $().ready(function () {
            $("a").on("click", function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                $('#lblModalMarcacao').text('Marcação: ' + $(this).attr("data-marcacao"));
            });
        });
    </script>
```

O modal:

```
    <div class="modal fade" id="myModal">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <div class="wrimagecard-topimage_header">
                    </div>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblModalMarcacao" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button class="btn btn-success btn-md" id="myButton">Sim</button>
                    <button class="btn btn-danger btn-md" data-dismiss="modal">Não</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

O link `<a>` estava sem a **tag** de fechamento.

Removi alguns scripts relacionados à modal, pois o acionamento ocorre no click do link sem a necessidade destes.

Verifique se a alteração abaixo resolve o problema.

```js
$().ready(function () {
    $("a").on("click", function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();                
        $('#lblModalMarcacao').text('Marcação: ' + $(this).attr("data-marcacao"));
    });
});
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" data-marcacao="frase">Abrir Modal</a>
    
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="wrimagecard-topimage_header">
                </div>
                <asp:Label ID="lblModalMarcacao" runat="server"></asp:Label>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button class="btn btn-success btn-md" id="myButton">Sim</button>
                <button class="btn btn-danger btn-md" data-dismiss="modal">Não</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```